# Do flags have some visible and/or linkable IDs?

Tags: support, flags, hyperlinks, flag-history, custom-flags

I would like to submit a custom flag with additional information<sup>1</sup> to supplement a previous flag I have submitted (which was found helpful but was not acted upon), and I would like to mention which flag of mine I meant. I've been looking for some ID or a link which would identify my previous flag - but couldn't find anything like that.

I'm assuming that if I said that "this is a continuation of a previous flag" it wouldn't be difficult for moderators to see past flags by myself, and find the flag I mean, but I'd prefer to make my new flag unambiguous.

**What is the preferred way to refer to a previous custom flag, within a new custom flag?**

<sup>1</sup> (if it matters: more evidence of violating site policies)

Comment: If the new flag is under the same post than the older flag, I'd say finding the "previous flag" would be pretty easy.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There's no direct way to refer to a flag. The preferred way to do so is either to

- Add a new flag onto the same post as the previous one
- Link to the post the previous flag was added onto in the flag body

or both.

If you can't remember on which post you've added your previous flag to, you can use the [My Flags page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/3372061) to find it (accessible from your profile page, under the Activity tab, "Helpful Flags")

Mods have flag views both per-user and per-post, so it's fairly easy for us to find previous flags in this fashion.